# What is a correct way to obtain FOnlineSubsystemSteam instance in c++ code

Tags: unreal-engine4, steam, steamworks-api

I'm trying to get steam app id and steam user id in my Unreal Engine 4 project in the following way:

```
if (SteamAPI_Init())
{
    IOnlineSubsystem* ossBase = IOnlineSubsystem::Get();
    FOnlineSubsystemSteam* oss = Cast<FOnlineSubsystemSteam*>(ossBase);

    if (!oss) {
        printText(TEXT("Steam Subsystem is down!"), FColor::Red.WithAlpha(255));
        return;
    }

    auto SteamID = FString(std::to_string(SteamUser()->GetSteamID().ConvertToUint64()).c_str());
    auto AppID = FString(std::to_string(oss->GetSteamAppId()).c_str());
```

But it is not possible to convert IOnlineSubsystem to FOnlineSubsystemSteam. So what is a correct way to obtain the instance of FOnlineSubsystemSteam?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use static_cast:

```
FOnlineSubsystemSteam* oss = static_cast<FOnlineSubsystemSteam*>(ossBase);
```

This one works. It seems obvious to use UE4 Cast, but in this case it does not work.